# Pulumi: How to configure ECS service for a CODE_DEPLOY controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, pulumi

While trying to set up a blue/green deployment I hit the following issue:

```
error: Plan apply failed: Error creating CodeDeploy deployment group: InvalidECSServiceException: Deployment group's ECS service must be configured for a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller.
    status code: 400, request id: b9314f00-ef3e-467e-a7b0-a3bd87600484
```

So far I tried to create `aws.ecs.Cluster` with custom settings and pass it to `awsx.ecs.Cluster` but the typing is not right:

```
const myCluster = new aws.ecs.Cluster('myCluster', {
    settings: {

    }
})
```

ends up with:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Input<ClusterSetting>[] | Promise<Input<ClusterSetting>[]> | OutputInstance<Input<ClusterSetting>[]> | undefined'.
```

and I am unable to find ClusterSetting type anywhere.

How do I set up ServiceDeploymentController type for a custom `aws.ecs.Cluster`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue and personally solved it like this. Basically had to lie to Typescript a little bit to make the types line up so that I could pass the correct deployment controller setting to the Fargate Service:

```js
const serviceArgs: FargateServiceArgs = {
  cluster,
  waitForSteadyState: false,
  taskDefinitionArgs: {
    cpu: "512",
    memory: "1024",
    containers: {
      nginx: {
        image: "nginx",
        portMappings: [blueListener]
      }
    }
  },
  desiredCount: 1
};

const deploymentContollerArgs = {
  deploymentController: {
    type: "CODE_DEPLOY"
  }
};

// TODO: This is here because @pulumi/awsx doesn't expose a nice way to set the deployment controller.
const combinedArgs: FargateServiceArgs = {
  ...serviceArgs,
  ...deploymentContollerArgs
};

export const laravelWebAppService = new awsx.ecs.FargateService(
  stackNamed("larvel-webapp-service"),
  {
    ...combinedArgs
  }
);


export const codeDeployGroup = new aws.codedeploy.DeploymentGroup(
  stackNamed("code-deploy-group"),
  {
    appName: codeDeployApplication.name,
    serviceRoleArn: role.arn,
    deploymentGroupName: stackNamed("code-deploy-group"),
    deploymentConfigName: "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce",
    deploymentStyle: {
      deploymentType: "BLUE_GREEN",
      deploymentOption: "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    },
    blueGreenDeploymentConfig: {
      deploymentReadyOption: {
        actionOnTimeout: "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
      },
      terminateBlueInstancesOnDeploymentSuccess: {
        action: "TERMINATE",
        terminationWaitTimeInMinutes: 1
      }
    },
    ecsService: {
      clusterName: cluster.cluster.name,
      serviceName: laravelWebAppService.service.name
    },
    loadBalancerInfo: {
      targetGroupPairInfo: {
        prodTrafficRoute: {
          listenerArns: [blueListener.listener.arn]
        },
        testTrafficRoute: {
          listenerArns: [greenListener.listener.arn]
        },
        targetGroups: [
          {
            name: blueTargetGroup.targetGroup.name
          },
          {
            name: greenTargetGroup.targetGroup.name
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
);
```